# database table design. Several tables with unique identifier one to one

Tags: sql-server, database, one-to-one

Im looking for advice on how  to structure my one to one tables, 1 'master' table to several tables. SQL Server.

The 'master' table only stores the descriptor and id for what used to be an enumeration. (I guess it could be classed as a lookup table where each value can only be used once)

The remaining tables represent several TPH groups of readonly classes. Each of the classes gets its id from the ex-enumeration. One class per enumeration value.

The dataset only changes when new products are designed by the company.
I have a primary, unique key on the 'master' table.

What do I do on the several other tables to ensure integrity? Am I even able to do this except by being very careful when adding new classes? Extra columns? Do I create relationships?  If so, which sort?

Comment: This sounds like you are creating the "one lookup table to rule them all". This is problematic for a number of reasons. It is challenging to ensure your data is valid. And more problematic is that the performance can get super nasty here. Consider a dozen users loading a page with a dozen lookups. That is now 144 queries across a single table. I did this once on a system and it was horrible as the amount of users ramped up.

Comment: The enum was originally intended to define consts for the product ids.It's not intended for more than that. so no joins. Once it's used in class table, that's it, its then used as an id in that table rather than an auto generated guid or int. Maybe it should just be ignored unless a new class is added?